# How can I strip a string with different ends in Python for scrapy bot?

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm building a scrapy spider but need efficient and correct way of stripping the string which contains the url. The url always starts with **['u** and ends with **']** 
For example [u'http://example.com/2334878']

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='category']/a"):
        item = SpiderItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract()
        linkToPost = str(item['link'])
        linkToPost = linkToPost.strip("['u")
        linkToPost = linkToPost.replace("'", "")
        linkToPost = linkToPost.replace("]", "")
        print linkToPost
        #Parse request to follow the posting link into the actual post
        request = scrapy.Request(linkToPost , callback=self.parse_item_page)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request
```

Comment: Is the code you provided not working? If so, what is the output? Or are you asking if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: The code works. There must be a cleaner way of doing this. But the extract90[0] method works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [`extract()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract) would return you a *list*:

> `extract()`
>
> Serialize and return the matched nodes as a list of
>   unicode strings. Percent encoded content is unquoted.

The most "scrapic" approach here would be to use an [`ItemLoader`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#module-scrapy.loader) and the [`TakeFirst`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.TakeFirst) or [`Join`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.Join) processor.

Alternatively, just get the first element from the list:

```
item['title'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
item['link'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
```